# can not install expo-cli?

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo

I'm trying to install the `expo-cli` package from npm. But everytime I do it I get this error, and I don't know why is this happening?

```
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.0.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.2 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\bin\expo.js
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm\expo.cmd
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, cmd shim 'C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\bin\expo.js' -> 'C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm\expo.cmd'
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm\expo.cmd
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-17T09_52_53_814Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to C:\Users{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules and remove Expo folder
then go to C:\Users{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm\ and remove every expo related file
then reinstall it